# How to render a XML page sending data NODEJS

Tags: node.js, xml, express

I'm building an app that one of the client's requirements was a page built in XML instead of HTML.

In NodeJS, when we would like to render a new page we use `res.render('/pageName', {pageVariable: variableFromNodeJs})`; I tried the same when using XML but didn't worked.
Do you know why and how I can make it?

Comment: Every website you see is HTML, if your data isn't HTML, then it is going to be parsed to HTML. What exactly do you mean by "one of the client's requirements was a page built in XML instead of HTML" ? XML just stores data, is also uses tags like HMTL but apart from that, has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yep, that is in SAP UI5, to be exact, and UI5 use XML in the frontend liked to a HTML

Comment: Can you add `res.type('application/xml');` before calling `res.render`? And, let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

What does the XML look like? If it looks like XHTML, then you can send it directly to the browser "as is", and the browser will handle it fine. If it's your own XML vocabulary, for example

```
<purchaseOrder>
   <orderNumber>17<orderNumber>
   <supplierName>Amazon</supplierName>
   <value currency="SGD">1600</value>
</purchaseOrder>
```

then you're going to have to supply a stylesheet to render it. Usually people use XSLT for this (though in simple cases it can also be done with CSS). You can apply the XSLT stylesheet either on the server or in the browser. If you want to use the latest version of XSLT (3.0), then the Saxon-JS implementation [disclaimer: my company's product] is available both on Node.js and in the browser.